# Get a specific Activity from TabActivity or TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

How can I get a specific Activity from TabActivity or TabHost?

I tried `TabHost.getChildAt()`, but a `View` instance can't be casted to an `Activity` instance.

Or how do you get an Activity which is running in background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131769/2624806 http://stackoverflow.com/a/5399466/2624806 could help you here.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find `TabActivity.getLocalActivityManager().getActivity()`.

For me it worked using `TabActivity.getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()`.

Answer (score 2):

found the answer: just use `TabActivity.getLocalActivityManager().getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you're looking for, but I HIGHLY recommend not using TabActivity.  In all the projects I've worked on, we wound up yanking it out and just using buttons that look like tabs.

I also think its deprecated in 3.0, and certainly Ice cream.  They push the action bar.  I'd look for one of the available action bar libraries.

Comment: What was so bad about it that you stopped using it? How did you end up handling activity groups?